# PHP not valid permissions to mkdir in samba share

Tags: php, apache, permissions, centos7, samba

So I created a samaba share in centos7 im able to read/write with windows 10. however, my PHP script on an apache server running on the same centos VM returns false when is_writable is called.

I have tried setting the owner to nobody,Apache,and root on the share for testing purposes and since the site is strictly internal i have set permissions to 0777. I have moved the folder into a directory accessible by apache. fileperms() returns 16895 and get_current_user() returns root.

```
if(is_writable('/var/www/html/Barcodes/') == false){ 
    echo ' Hmm no write ';
    echo fileperms('/var/www/html/Barcodes/');       
    chmod('/var/www/html/Barcodes/', 0777);
    echo ' ';
    echo fileperms('/var/www/html/Barcodes/');
    echo ' '. get_current_user();
    die; 
}
```

it should return true, I then try set perms inside of php and test for change, no dice.

EDIT:
I disable SELinux which is not the true answer because of security flaws however it did make php able to r/w in the shared folder. so the issue comes down to chcon both httpd as well as samba

Answer (score 0):

Why are you hassling?
to create a directory, just go:

```
mkdir($PATH, 0777);
```

Comment: Sure this works but the problem is that Apache doesn't have permission to do that even though its in its accessible directory

Comment: Try the feopen() function